Why do I need the server certificate in my Azure Certificates store to use a Client Certificate?
I have a C# app, using HttpClient to connect to a remote server. The server owner has asked for Client Certificate authentication. I sent through the public key certificate to them, and loaded the .pfx certificate (which includes the private key) when I make the request.
I receive the following error:
The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

I now load the server owners public key certificate into my Azure Certificate store, in the "Public key certificates" area, and it works.
Why does loading their certificate make any difference? I already needed to ignore server side validation, as we are connecting via an IP address, as opposed to a URL. This is the configuration:
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
        handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData, password);
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            ...
        }

So, how is adding the server certificate doing anything? What have I missed?
(Note: The full error from outer to inner is:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

)

Does the user running the client app have the correct permissions on the private key on their machine? Or does certificateData already contain the private key?

I understand your confusion, and in addition, the error message you're showing doesn't look related to SSL/TLS. Are there other error messages or more details to this error message?

@Charlieface the client certificate has the private key. Asking the X509 it loaded into indicates it has it.

Does the PFX contain the full chain or only the leaf certificate?

Given that the thing started working when I put the server certificate in, I'm not sure what difference it makes what is in my certificate. As it is, it is a full chain.
